# How to Transpose dataframe column when duplicate entries exist in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, duplicates, transpose

I am having difficulty in transposing a certain column in python.

I have the following df

```
ID  Value  Date
1   15     2019/01/01  
1   13     2019/02/01  
1   17     2019/03/01  
2   16     2019/01/01  
2   14     2019/02/01  
2   15     2019/03/01
```

I want to create a df such that the duplicates from ID column are removed and the Values get transposed

```
ID  Value_01  Value_02  Value_03  
1   15        13        17  
2   16        14        15
```

Comment: ```df.astype('str').groupby("ID").Value.agg(','.join).str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix("Value_")``` ? u could work out the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `cumcount` with `groupby` to make your columns, then `crosstab`

```
df1 = df.assign(key=df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)

df2 = pd.crosstab(df1["ID"], df1["key"], df1["Value"], aggfunc='first').add_prefix(
    "Value_"
).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(df2)

   ID  Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
0   1       15       13       17
1   2       16       14       15
```

Comment: It says that DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crosstab'

Comment: @akrammalek `pd.crosstab` not `df.crosstab` ;)